# How to use angularjs template inside php project based on Zend

Tags: php, angularjs, templates, zend-framework, frameworks

I have php framework based on Zend library and I'd like to use angularjs script in phtml file but I have problem how to include template edytuj_row.phtml located in:

ProjectName->SourceFiles->application->admin->views->settings->edytuj.phtml

```
<div row-settings></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);

    app.directive('rowSettings', function(){
        return {
            templateUrl: 'edytuj_row.phtml'            
        };
    });
</script>
```

Both files `edytuj_row.phtml` and `edytuj.phtml` are localizated in the same directory but edytuj_row.phtml is not seen. What is right path in `templateUrl` ? In this situation in place of `<div row-settings></div>` is loaded recurently main web page instead of template.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has no access to Zend files (templates). You need to set valid URL to `templateUrl` (eg. `/admin/users/edytuj-row`)

You probably have `edytujAction` and `edytujRowAction`. Check what URL path directs to `edytujRowAction` (probably in Bootstrap.php) and set it in `templateUrl`.